# I want to write the code I created with the 'Stored procedure' as a function

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE PROC add_person
(
    @id tinyint,
    @name nvarchar(max),
    @surname nvarchar(max),
    @salary int,
    @job nvarchar(max)
)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO information
    VALUES(@id,@name,@surname,@salary,@job)
END
```

I want to write this code as a function. But the concept of "**return**" confuses me. That's why I couldn't.

I tried to write the code above as a function. This code came out.

```
CREATE FUNCTION add_person
(
    @id tinyint,
    @name nvarchar(max),
    @surname nvarchar(max),
    @salary int,
    @job nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN INSERT INTO information -- not work
    VALUES(@id,@name,@surname,@salary,@job)
END
```

Comment: You cannot execute an `insert` in a function, so stick with the stored procedure.

Comment: `RETURN` is *normally* used to signify if an SP was successful or return some kind of status code; and you can only have one return value. This sounds like you would be better off with `OUTPUT` parameters.

Comment: What is your reason for wanting a function instead of an SP?

Comment: @DaleBurrell I wanted to do something like this in functions. But I forgot that DML operations were not performed in functions.

Comment: I understand *what* you were trying to do, but I was trying to understand *why* :)

Comment: I tried to write the code I wrote with "SP" with the function. I just wanted to try. There's no reason :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions are much more limited in their functionality than are stored procedures.

Although `insert` is allowed, it is only allowed in local variables.  As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) says:

> - INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements modifying local table variables.

On the other hand, a stored procedure *can* return a value.  Normally, this is a status code, where 0 means everything succeeded, and any other value means that the process failed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return the newly created table, you can use the stored procedure to do that.  If you're using SQL Server, the code would be:

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO information -- not work
    VALUES(@id,@name,@surname,@salary,@job);
    SELECT * FROM information WHERE id = @@identity; -- this is the primary key just created.
END
```

Comment: "return" returns an error because I haven't returned a value.